# Help for $\int_0^{\pi^2}\int_\sqrt{x}^{\pi} \sin(y^3) \,\mathrm{d}y \,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, iterated-integrals

**SOLUTION**

$$\begin{aligned}
I &=\int_\sqrt{x}^{\pi}\int_0^{\pi^2} \sin(y^3) \,\mathrm{d}y \,\mathrm{d}x \\
&=\int_\sqrt{x}^{\pi}\int_0^{\pi^2} \sin(y^3) \,\mathrm{d}x \,\mathrm{d}y \\
&=\int_\sqrt{x}^{\pi} \pi^2 \sin(y^3) \,\mathrm{d}y
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189)
Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others
there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people
will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation,
and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: Hint: change the order of integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to integrate the function $f(x,y)=\sin (y^3)$ with bounds $\int_{x=0}^{x=\pi^2}\int_{y=\sqrt x}^{y=\pi}$.

This can be represented as the set

\begin{align}
\ S & =\{ (x,y) \in \Bbb R^2:0≤x≤\pi^2 \;,\; \sqrt x≤y≤\pi \} \\
\ & =\{ (x,y) \in \Bbb R^2:0≤x≤\pi^2 \;,\; x≤y^2≤\pi^2 \} \\
\ & =\{ (x,y) \in \Bbb R^2:0≤x≤y^2≤\pi^2 \} \\
\ & = \{ (x,y) \in \Bbb R^2:0≤y^2≤\pi^2 \;,\; 0≤x≤y^2\} \\
\ & = \{ (x,y) \in \Bbb R^2:0≤y≤\pi \;,\; 0≤x≤y^2\}
\end{align}

Basically this is our region:

[image]

Thus, another way to parameterize this region is to have $\int_{y=0}^{y=\pi}\int_{x=0}^{x=y^2}$ instead. Hence

\begin{align}
\ \int_{x=0}^{x=\pi^2}\int_{y=\sqrt x}^{y=\pi}\sin (y^3)dydx & = \int_{y=0}^{y=\pi}\int_{x=0}^{x=y^2}\sin (y^3)dxdy\\
\ & = \int_{y=0}^{y=\pi} y^2\sin (y^3)dy \\
\ & = \Bigl[ -\frac 13 \cos(y^3) \Bigr]_{y=0}^{y=\pi} \\
\ & = \frac 13 \Bigl (1-\cos (\pi ^3) \Bigr )
\end{align}